# kill process which is loaded by launchagents

Tags: macos, launchd

My app(my.app) will add an plist file(com.agent.plist) to `/Library/LaunchAgents`, and it will trigger another app(agent.app) when my.app is runatload. I know that the agent.app will be loaded as non-root permission because it is in `/Library/LaunchAgents`.
Next time, in the uninstall script of my.app, i want to user `launchtl remove com.agent.plist` to kill the agent.app process. But the uninstall script is triggerred by root permission, so it seems like using `sudo launchtl remove com.agent.plist`, this doesn't work becuase agent.app is not owned by root.

So anyone can tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is…challenging. This is the inverse version of [How can you start a LaunchAgent for the first time without rebooting, when your code runs as a LaunchDaemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896274/how-can-you-start-a-launchagent-for-the-first-time-without-rebooting-when-your/7896450).

You can use the same code as given in that answer; just replace `load -w <your_plist>` with `remove <your_bundle>`.