# OS X 10.11 EL Capitan: Start launch agent for all logged in users from daemom

Tags: macos, launchd, osx-elcapitan

I am having with one daemon(A) which downloads one .pkg for daemon(B) from server and installs it also place daemon(B) in /Library/MyFolder/. it also place two global launch agent in same directory and corresponding plists in /Library/LaunchAgents. Application bundle of daemon(B) contains one wrapper app say launcher which loads launch agents for all  logged in users and I am using below scripts to open launcher app on 10.10

```
for num in `ps ax | grep MacOS/loginwindow| cut -c 1-5`;
do
if [ $num -ne 1 ]
then
sudo launchctl bsexec $num  /Library/MyFolder/daemon(b).app/Contents/MacOS/Launcher
fi
done.
```

Above script work fine on 10.10 but not working on 10.11 EL Capitan. Is it because of the rootless feature of 10.11 because if I disable rootless same scripts works fine. Also If i install .pkg for daemon(B) manually that tim also it work fine. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896274/how-can-you-start-a-launchagent-for-the-first-time-without-rebooting-when-your?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search for '/usr/sbin/pboard' instead of 'MacOS/loginwindow'. Apple denied access to loginwindow process.

EDIT: This is no longer working. See comments for details.

Comment: No, it doesn't work I am getting same error task_for_pid() = 0*5

Comment: Issue is not from MacOS/loginwindow.I am suspecting it is becuase of launchctl bsexec.

Comment: I'm currently in solving same problem, so I found that following works:
1) To launch agent for user

    sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/<userID> <jobPlist>

2) To execute task under user context: 
Found PID of /System/Library/CoreServices/iconservicesagent process for user, then run 
    sudo launchctl bsexec <PID> <command>

Comment: You are right, in latest Developer Preview 3 my way to call 'launchctl bsexec' didn't work. Apple has locked all system processes.

Comment: as per the man page of launchctl on 10.11 bsexec is under legacy subcommand which might be unimplemented in 10.11. However as u suggested 1)To launch agent for user sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/<userID> <jobPlist>  works well, but again it has two more command kickstart and enable that is related to bootstrap only that needs be checked. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/33259

Comment: kickstart – is a replacement for legacy start;
kickstart -k – is a replacement for legacy stop&start;
enable|disable – is a replacement for legacy -w argument for load|unload;

Comment: And for now there is no way to execute command without creating job plist.