# launch agent executing with root account in Yosemite

Tags: macos, launchd, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to execute my test daemon by launchd with logon user privilege.
I saved my plist file at `/Library/LaunchAgents/myplist` and it was executed well with logon user account at Mavericks.
My command was like this.

`$launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/myplist`

But it was executed as root account when I tried it at Yosemite.
As I know, it should be executed as logon user account, but it wasn't at Yosemite. I also moved myplist file to `~/Library/LauchAgents/myplist`, but the result was same.
What happend to Launchd at Yosemite and how can I execute launchd with logon user account?

Comment: Your daemon was launched as `root` when you put your plist into the `~/Library/LauchAgents/myplist`? Is your daemon `setuid root` by any chance?

Comment: Yes. It was executed with root when I put my plist into the ~/Library/LaunchAgents/myplist. My daemon never setuid, it's just a simple nohup command like "nohup mydaemon > /tmp/mydaemon.log 2> /tmp/mydaemon.log &".

Answer (score 0):

The user can be specified in the daemon's plist with the **UserName** key. For example: -

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>_daemonUser</string>
```

Where **_daemonUser** is the name of the user the daemon should run as, assuming that a user with that name exists.

If you want to use the name of the current logged-in user, you'll have to specify that when calling *launchctl load*. In a bash script, run with sudo, you can do something like this: -

```
SESSION_USER="$USER"
echo Starting MyDaemon as user $SESSION_USER
su $SESSION_USER -c 'launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/myplist.plist'
```

You may need to consider other users too, if user switching is applicable and they're already logged-in. This is more complicated, but there's a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106638/starting-stopping-a-launchd-agent-for-all-users-with-gui-sessions/31534614#31534614).

Comment: I've already tried UserName key, but it didn't work. Still executed with root account. As I mentioned, It's just happend at Yosemite only, it's executed with logon user account at Mavericks. Any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry @jay, is launchd running as root? As the [Apple Docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) for UserName *This optional key specifies the user to run the job as. This key is only applicable when launchd is running as root.*